# ElasticSearch: Check if a field is informed

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch as primary backend infrastructure.

Currently, I need to know whether a field is informed, so, I need to know `#documents with a field 'x' > 0`.

Imagine a collection with these two documents:

```
[ {
      "_index" : "living_v1",
      "_type" : "fuas",
      "_id" : "58fb4509-9452-11e6-a361-02420a016207",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_routing" : "living_team",
      "_source" : {
        "user" : "living_team",
        "timestamp" : "2016-10-17T10:29:27.037Z",
        "startTimestamp" : "2016-10-17T10:29:27.037Z",
        "dueTimestamp" : null,
        "closingTimestamp" : null,
        "matter" : "FUA1",
        "comment" : null,
        "status" : 0,
        "backlogStatus" : 20,
        "metainfos" : {
          "cabeaacaceaacadeaacaeeaacafeaa" : [ "s11" ],
          "cdbccaeacdbccaeacdbccaeacdbccaeacdbccaea_ldate" : [ "2016-10-19T07:08:23.130Z" ]
        },
        "resources" : [ ],
        "notes" : null
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "living_v1",
      "_type" : "fuas",
      "_id" : "2298eab3-9a8a-11e6-8f4a-02420a010a07",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_routing" : "living_team",
      "_source" : {
        "user" : "living_team",
        "timestamp" : "2016-10-25T09:53:23.078Z",
        "startTimestamp" : "2016-10-25T09:53:23.078Z",
        "dueTimestamp" : null,
        "closingTimestamp" : null,
        "matter" : "FUA2",
        "comment" : null,
        "status" : 0,
        "backlogStatus" : 20,
        "metainfos" : {
          "aecfacebfaaecfcebfaaecfcebfaaecfcebfaaecfcebfa" : [ "s22" ]
        },
        "resources" : [ ],
        "notes" : null
      }
    } ]
```

I'd like to know how many documents have a field `status` informed. For example, if I want to know if a field named `exfield` is informed, the response will be `NO`, nevertheless, if I want to know if a field named `matter` is informed the response will be `YES`.

Does exist anyway to do that?

Comment: Is it possible to give some more details, like an example with your document etc.?

Comment: I hope this time it's a bit more clear.

Comment: A bit more clear but i do not get what do you mean by the term `informed`? You can check if a field `exists` in your document or not, something like that would suit your needs? Also, I cannot tell if you do it but it is not a good practice to have fields with `null` values. It is better to not exist at all

Comment: are you looking to check if the field exists in **all** documents or **some** documents? also please be clear about the term _informed_?

Comment: yes, I need exactly _to check if a field exists in all documents_.